# Print out every MAC address seen on a network interface?

Tags: networking

Is there a foolproof way to discover the MAC address of a device that is freshly plugged into an ethernet network in linux?

I'm looking specifically for something that works on the MAC address level.  Assume everything at the ip address level is broken.

i.e. maybe ethernet chip drivers expose a list of the MAC's they've seen in /proc?

Comment: Some scripting using the arp table should be enough I think, no?

Comment: Nope, the device doesn't show in the arp table.  I need link-level stuff.  tcpdump and/or tshark.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083014/get-only-the-source-mac-address-from-tcpdump

Answer (score 0):

Taken from a similar question, this gets pretty close:

```
sudo tshark -i eth0 -e eth.src -Tfields
```

However, it doesn't de-duplicate lines, and it seems there are intermittent line number prefixes.